# How to make a dynamic FFI in .NET?

Tags: .net, dynamic, f#, ffi

I am building a small interpreter, in F# and in order to make it more useful I would like to be able to add as a feature the possibility to call foreign functions (from C probably). So I'm looking to make a dynamic FFI, to be clear I want to have a way to call functions from a lib written in C for which I specify some information *during the runtime* of my interpreter (as the name and the types).

There may be a way to do what I'm looking for libraries written for the .NET platform, written in C# for example, but I would be more interested if it were for libraries written in C.

In C, there is the [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) library but to my knowledge no port has been made for the .NET platform (there is [a thing on Nugget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/libffi), but after trying it I realized that it didn't provide anything).

What way do I have to do this?